# How to remove . (several lines of customized programming code appear here) from wordpress pages

Tags: plugins

I have got a task to edit a wordpress website. On each page i see this line. . (several lines of customized programming code appear here).. how can i remove it? I have tried much but couldn't find from wordpress admin panel or from cpanel

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solution. go to wp-content/themes/your theme/header.php. here you will find this line. just remove it.